# How to Hide default help_text fom date fields in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a django model that has one date field.

```
class Employee(AbstractUser):
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of Birth", null=True)
```

when i register this model in admin site and display this field on the form during update, I see this default text for date fields.

[image]

How can i remove this default help_text 
`Note: You are 5.5 hours ahead of server time`

I tried to override the help_text for date feild but it didn't work.

```
dob = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of Birth", null=True, help_text='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,  `Note: You are 5.5 hours ahead of server time` isn't your provided `help_text`. You can check this after providing a different `help_text` to `models.py`.
**How to remove this Note ?**
Assuming your server running on **Asia/Kolkata** timezone and you are declared `TIME_ZONE=UTC` in `settings.py`. In order to remove that Note from admin page, you have to set  `TIME_ZONE=Asia/Kolkata`